# DotNetNuke 5.6 + DNNRadMenu = Terribly Slow Debugging (100% CPU usage in 1 Core for 30 seconds)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, telerik, dotnetnuke, radmenu

When i do the following, I have one CPU core that sits at 100% utilization for about 30 seconds (page does not finish loading until this 30 seconds is up).

1. Add RadMenu to a skin
2. Load a page that uses that skin
3. Confirm that the page loaded OK (DNN recompile went fine...)
4. Turn on debugging (attach to w3wp.exe in VS2010)
5. Refresh page

wait 30 seconds...

When I remove the RadMenu from the skin, the thing debugs immediately.

I'm using the DNN download for RadMenu http://dnnradmenu.codeplex.com/

Any tips?

I've tried:

- removing most other skin object references in the skin
- replicating behavior on multiple pages, multiple skins
- Telling VStudio to ignore symbols named: *radmenu* (I don't know if this catches those items in
  the asp.net temp files folder) and the telerik (huge) DLL in dnn/bin
- turned off most debugging 'extra' features in VS2010
- Set debug=false in the radmenu ascx file

I don't know if there's a new version available. I've got the only version available on that download site.

DNN 5.6.x Community, Radmenu 1.0, VS2010 (latest SP/etc), IIS7, .Net Framework 4.0, Win7 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unfortunate solution to this problem is to disable the DNNRadMenu when debugging in Visual Studio is necessary. I have added two shortcuts on my Desktop. One renames DNNRadMenu.ASCX (to disable), and the other shortcut renames it back (to enable).

The above issue may not be a problem with the Telerik controls made available in non-community versions of DNN.

The above issue only concerns the DNNRadMenu that is made available for community as of 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the RadMenu skin object that Telerik provides?  With your Telerik components, there should be an additional DNN download which contains a Skin Objects package.

Comment: @bdukes, I will try to locate the RadMenu skin object. So far, I am not familiar with it. This may be because I'm using the DNN Rad Menu that is now provided free of charge to community-edition users, as I suspect you may be referring to a paid feature. However, I will see what I can scrounge up. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I don't think that the license for Telerik allows you to use that RadMenu control without a license for the Telerik controls.  That component doesn't use a DNN wrapper for the menu, which are the only components (AFAIK) that are licensed for DNN developers without Telerik licenses.  The component that I am talking about also requires a Telerik license (it comes along with the WebControls package).

Comment: @bdukes, pretty sure DNNRadMenu free to use now for community (but you don't get the source code). Please see: http://i.imgur.com/EZGiy.png    telerik partnership faq: http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/telerik-dnn-partnership-qanda.aspx.   Unfortunately looks like I may be out of luck as far as the free license goes, but I'll still look into it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The FAQ that you link to states: "Community Edition developers will only be able to develop though standard user interface extensions provided with the core platform."  The image that you posted is the license for the DNNRadMenu wrapper control, but only applies to that code, not to the Telerik component.  http://dnnradmenu.codeplex.com/ states "Developers should review whether they need a telerik or DotNetNuke Professional license for their purposes."

Comment: This is confusing to me. Can I use the wrapper with the community edition (which uses the Telerik DLL that ships with community) or can I not? My interpretation is that we can use the wrapper (even modify it), but we can't have access to the code for the core telerik components unless we purchase a license for the profession or enteprise DNN versions. Guess I should just open up another quesion here. I'll post a link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781983/dotnetnuke-can-community-edition-users-utilize-the-dnnradmenu

Comment: From that thread, we've determined that the skin object was developed by a licensed party, so it can be deployed wherever. It is _not_ using the "standard user interface extensions," and so requires a Telerik license to alter the source.  In the future, it will be updated to use the standard extensions (once they're available in DNN 6), which will allow anyone to alter the source.  Sorry for any undue concern my questioning caused, glad we're in the clear.

Comment: BDukes, you just sparked a good conversation. I'm glad it's out in the open for others now on stackoverflow.