# DotNetNuke 5.6.2 - Can Community Edition Users utilize the DNNRadMenu?

Tags: licensing, telerik, dotnetnuke

There is uncertainty surrounding the use of DNNRadMenu in the community edition of DotNetNuke.

It is my understanding that as of DNN 5.6.2, it is OK for community edition users to use (and modify) the DNNRadMenu wrapper, but these users/developers will not have access to the core telerik code (which is bundled into an enormous DLL that ships with all versions of DNN).

DNN RadMenu is obtained here:
http://dnnradmenu.codeplex.com/

From the DNN / Telerik partnership Q&A
http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/telerik-dnn-partnership-qanda.aspx

> DotNetNuke Community Edition users
>   will be able to develop using
>   RadControls through standard user
>   interface extensions  provided in the
>   DotNetNuke platform. Community Edition
>   developers will have more limited
>   access to the Telerik RadControls than
>   Professional Edition developers and
>   will not have full developer license
>   rights to use the Telerik RadControls
>   toolset. Community Edition developers
>   will only be able to develop though
>   standard user interface extensions
>   provided with the core platform.

**Can community edition users freely deploy the DNN RadMenu (within DNN installations)?**

My interpretation is that we can tweak the DNN RadMenu SkinObject all we want, but we will not have access to the core telerik code. I know there is a strong desire (from DNN Corp) for shops like mine to subscribe to DNN Pro or Enterprise, but sometimes that is just not in the budget for a particular project. I feel like part of the reason for this partnership is to give access to these controls, like DNNRadMenu, to community edition clients so as to increase the pervasiveness of the controls... which ought to increase sales for licenses for greater access to the controls. If I am correct with these assumptions, then I would like to take advantage of the opportuntiy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can community edition users freely
>   deploy the DNN RadMenu (within DNN
>   installations)?

Yep - any Telerik stuff that is wrapped by DNN can be used in a Community Edition installation.

Comment: Is the DNN RadMenu project "wrapped by DNN," or is it a third party component that is not associated with DNN corp?  My understanding is that "wrappers" only refers to the types in DotNetNuke.Web.UI

Comment: Although not implemented in the same manner as the other wrappers, I am told from an official source that the DNNRadMenu skin object is safe for use in CE without a Telerik license. You just can't modify it without a license.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the DNN RadMenu project "wrapped by
>   DNN," or is it a third party component
>   that is not associated with DNN corp?
>   My understanding is that "wrappers"
>   only refers to the types in
>   DotNetNuke.Web.UI

Under the current licensing, you cannot modify the dnnradmenu or any of the other skin objects (I posted) because they are not using the core Telerik wrappers (unless you are a PE/EE customer or have a valid Telerik license). They currently do not use the wrappers because as of dnn 5.6.2 they didn't exist. Once 6.0 is a public release (not CTP/Beta), this will change and I will update all the skin objects to use the new wrappers and then anyone can modify the skin objects without licensing concerns.

Also, as an FYI, the DDR Menu will be the new default navigation in 6.0 (not the current DNN Menu or a Telerik alternative).

Comment: I understand, based upon your response, that we cannot modify the DNNRadMenu skin object under the Community Edition license. However, are we free to use the DNNRadMenu skin object in the community edition without modification? Thanks

Comment: Sorry hamlin11, forgot about this post. Yes, what you said is correct (once 6.0 drops and a new skin object is released, this will change).